# Creating a query variance (difference) analysis in Microsoft Access

Tags: sql, ms-access, variance

I have a specific task that I need help with.

Essentially I have a Sales table:

```
Product_ID/No   Product_Name    Date          Revenue
       A              APPLE     01-01-20       50
       B              BANANA    01-01-20       100
       A              APPLE     15-12-19       50
       B              BANANA    15-12-19       150
       C              CHERRY    15-12-19       50
       A              APPLE     01-01-20       60
```

I need to create a variance report (difference/movement) from this table on a monthly level, with the following headers:

```
Product_ID/No   Product_Name    Current_Month   Previous_Month  Variance
    A             Apple             110         50               60
    B             Banana            100         150             -50
    C             Cherry            50          -50
```

#### Questions:

How can I do this?

Will this be a series of SQL statements?

Any advice would be appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: Please describe what YOU mean by "variance".  Desired results would help.

Comment: yes, of course. Apologies for not being clear. I'll update the post.

Comment: Which DBMS are you actually using. The query for this in sql server will be vastly different than Access.

Comment: This will just be in Access for now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can group by product and use conditional aggregation:

```
SELECT 
  [Product_ID/No], [Product_Name], 
  SUM(IIF(DATESERIAL(YEAR(DATE()), MONTH(DATE()), 1) = DATESERIAL(YEAR([Date]), MONTH([Date]), 1), Revenue, NULL)) AS Current_Month,
  SUM(IIF(DATESERIAL(YEAR(DATEADD("m", -1, DATE())), MONTH(DATEADD("m", -1, DATE())), 1) = DATESERIAL(YEAR([Date]), MONTH([Date]), 1), Revenue, NULL)) AS Previous_Month,
  Nz(Current_Month)- Nz(Previous_Month) AS Variance
FROM Sales
GROUP BY [Product_ID/No], [Product_Name]
```

Results:

```
Product_ID/No   Product_Name    Current_Month   Previous_Month  Variance
A               APPLE           110             50              60
B               BANANA          100             150             -50
C               CHERRY                          50              -50
```

Answer (score -1):

this query is for SQL Server :

```
WITH Temp
AS (SELECT [Product_ID/No],
           [Product_Name],
           ISNULL(SUM(IIF(DATEPART(MONTH, GETDATE()) = DATEPART(MONTH, [Date]), Revenue, NULL)), 0) AS Current_Month,
           ISNULL(SUM(IIF(DATEPART(MONTH, DATEADD(MONTH, -1, GETDATE())) = DATEPART(MONTH, [Date]), Revenue, NULL)), 0) AS Previous_Month
    FROM dbo.Sales
    GROUP BY [Product_ID/No],
             [Product_Name])
SELECT *,
       (Temp.Current_Month - Temp.Previous_Month) AS Variance
FROM Temp;
```